# Best Option(s) for Running Python ETL Code in AWS

Tags: python-3.x, amazon-s3, aws-lambda, aws-glue, aws-batch

I am looking for a recommendation on which AWS service (or combination thereof) to use to execute an ETL code in Python to transform text-based files:

Description of the code/process:
1. Python code transforms input text files from a custom vendor format into CSV format.
2. Single Python code invocation transforms a single file and can run anywhere from a minute to 10 mins or more as the sizes of input files vary (from KBs to 100s of MBs).
3. Python code needs to run as an event as soon as the new input file is ready, which can happen any time, multiple times a day.
4. I need to use AWS serverless options, hence no EC2.

My current solution is to use Lambda/S3 Event to detect the creation of the new files in S3, "move" it to the appropriate folder in the same S3 bucket and trigger AWS Glue Python Shell Job to transform it. I believe AWS EMR is an overkill for the sizes of the files being transformed (

However, I am open to better recommendations as AWS Glue so far does not appear as robust and mature as other services (like Lambda).
If my current solution appears sound, please chime in anyway, this will help me to make sure I am on the right path!

Thank you,
Michael :)

Comment: you could also do the processing in Lambda: stream from S3, or save to /tmp . you could write your own SerDe to read the input file, and use Athena to save it as CSV

Comment: Thank you for the answer Neil!

Can you provide more details?

1. Athena does not support custom SerDe's besides the ones already provided:
https://aws.amazon.com/athena/faqs/
So, I cannot write my own SerDe for reading my custom formatted files.

2. Where will SerDe run? In which service? As I've mentioned above, I cannot run the ETL code entirely within Lambda function.

Apologies for any confusion. I hope you could clarify further.

Comment: oh ya you're right, no custom serdes.

Answer (score 1):

We can configure a Lambda S3 event trigger on the landing folder and when a file is uploaded, we can have a brief script in Lambda to trigger the Glue job.  The glue python script should have required logic to convert the input text files into a CSV files.  This way your job can be run any number of times when a file is uploaded to the S3.

Your billing is also only for the duration of the job is run.  Please be aware that the cost is little high in Glue due to its managed services feature.

Have the event trigger created , trigger the glue job. Please find herewith a code snippet for AWS Lambda:

```
from __future__ import print_function
import json
import boto3
import time
import sys
import time
from datetime import datetime

s3 = boto3.client('s3')
glue = boto3.client('glue')

def lambda_handler(event, context):
    gluejobname="<< THE GLUE JOB NAME >>"

    try:
        runId = glue.start_job_run(JobName=gluejobname)
        status = glue.get_job_run(JobName=gluejobname, RunId=runId['JobRunId'])
        print("Job Status : ", status['JobRun']['JobRunState'])
    except Exception as e:
        print(e)
        print('Error getting object {} from bucket {}. Make sure they exist '
              'and your bucket is in the same region as this '
              'function.'.format(source_bucket, source_bucket))
    raise e
```